# plotting timeseries wiggle section using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, matrix

i have a .mat file .I want to read its each column which contain timeseries data(10 nos) and want to make a wiggle plot section by arranging the timeseries side by side using matplotlib library package.where x axis will be timeseries number and y axis will be time samples.

I tried below script

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


c1 = h5py.File('test_data.mat', 'r')  
out1=c1.get('dat')
for x in range(10):
   dd=out1[x]
   plt.plot(np.arange(len(dd)), dd)
   plt.show()
```

But it does not give wiggle plot section.please suggest a better solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Likely there are simpler way to do this in other libraries, but using matplotlib only, you can achieve this using a combination of `fill.betweenx` and `subplots`. (Most of the other code is for aesthetics and can be modified to improve readability or match your taste.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

dat = np.ndarray(buffer=np.sin(np.random.uniform(size=1000)), shape=(100, 10))
dat[:, [1, 4, 6]] = np.log(dat[:, [1, 4, 6]])

numplots = dat.shape[1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, numplots)
for i in range(numplots):
    # Define series and indexes
    y = dat[:, i]
    ym = y.mean()
    idx = np.arange(len(y))

    # Plot series
    ax[i].plot(y, idx)

    # Fill when series > mean
    ax[i].fill_betweenx(
        idx, y, ym, where=y > y.mean(), color="Orange", interpolate=True
    )

    # Fill when series <= mean
    ax[i].fill_betweenx(idx, y, ym, where=y <= y.mean(), color="Gray", interpolate=True)

    # Optional aesthetics
    ax[i].set_xlabel("Series " + str(i))
    if (i < numplots - 1) & (i > 0):
        ax[i].spines["right"].set_visible(False)
        ax[i].spines["left"].set_visible(False)
        ax[i].yaxis.set_ticks([])

# Final adjustments
ax[0].spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax[numplots - 1].spines["left"].set_visible(False)
ax[numplots - 1].yaxis.set_ticks([])
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0)
plt.show()
```

Producing the following:[image]

NOTE HORIZONTAL ALIGNMENT: I took inspiration from this [picture](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/38691/versions/2/screenshot.png). However, if you want the plot to be shown horizontally, change the code above with the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(numplots, 1)
for i in range(numplots):
    # Define series and indexes
    y = dat[:, i]
    ym = y.mean()
    idx = np.arange(len(y))
    # Plot series
    ax[i].plot(idx, y)
    # Fill when series > mean
    ax[i].fill_between(idx, y, ym, where=y > y.mean(), color="Orange", interpolate=True)
    # Fill when series <= mean
    ax[i].fill_between(idx, y, ym, where=y <= y.mean(), color="Gray", interpolate=True)
    # Optional aesthetics
    ax[i].set_ylabel("Series " + str(i), rotation=0, labelpad=40)
    ax[i].xaxis.set_ticks([])
    if (i < numplots - 1) & (i > 0):
        ax[i].spines["top"].set_visible(False)
        ax[i].spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
# Final adjustments
ax[0].spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax[numplots - 1].spines["top"].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

producing this:
[image]